# jQuery loop find last data attribute with a value of true and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following loop that selects each accordion element on the page and checks if the data attribute is true (each accordion element is a step in a process), if the data attribute is true the active class is applied and the accordion is expanded. However, I would like to apply the active class to the last element with the data attribute of true only.

jQuery:

```
var $steps = $('dd.accordion-navigation.workspace-step');

$steps.each(function () {

    var stepComplete = $(this).data('workspace-step-complete');

    if (stepComplete === true) {
        $(this).addClass('active')
            .find('.content')
            .addClass('active');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<dd class="accordion-navigation workspace-step" data-workspace-step-complete="true">
<!-- Apply active class to this step only -->
<dd class="accordion-navigation workspace-step" data-workspace-step-complete="true">
<dd class="accordion-navigation workspace-step" data-workspace-step-complete="false">
<dd class="accordion-navigation workspace-step" data-workspace-step-complete="false">
<dd class="accordion-navigation workspace-step" data-workspace-step-complete="false">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using attribute equals selector , `:last` selector `.is()`

```
var $steps = $('dd.accordion-navigation.workspace-step');

$steps.each(function () {

    $(this).is("[data-workspace-step-complete=true]:last") &&    
    $(this).addClass('active')
    .find('.content')
    .addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as expected. I tried `.is` and `:last` but couldn't get it to work. I was missing the `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the attribute 'data-workspace-step-complete' using `attr` function and then check if value is true and perform respective operation.

```
    var $steps = $('.accordion-navigation.workspace-step');
var i = -1;

$steps.each(function () {
    var stepComplete = $(this).attr("data-workspace-step-complete");
    if (stepComplete == "true") {
            i++;
        }    
});
```

`i` would now give you the index of last element with attr = "true".

```
var LastElementwithTrue = $('.accordion-navigation.workspace-step').eq(1);
```

Comment: This will add the active class to every workspace step with the data attribute of true, which does the same thing as my question. I'm looking to add the active class to the last data attribute with the value of true only.

Answer (score 0):

The [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) method should target the needed element:

```
$('[data-workspace-step-complete=true]').last().addClass('active')
```